# My dog ate yeast balls

Tags: large-dogs

I was making rolls and the yeast failed and i baked it for 15 minutes at 350F . Will it still hurt my dog? I haven’t tried anything yet, he’s currently laying down and acting normal.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: If you’re seriously worried or your dog shows any unusual symptoms, call your vet.**

That said, he’s probably fine.
If your dough didn’t rise because the yeast failed *and* it was exposed to oven heat afterwards, then you can assume that either all or at least the vast majority of the yeast cells were dead by the time your dog munched on your rolls. The rest is maths: even if he consumed a very small amount of miraculously vital yeast, the time these cells would need to multiply to digest the carbohydrates in the bread at a rate that produces an amount of either CO2 or alcohol big enough to cause trouble is counteracted by what the digestive tract of your dog does to both the yeast and the carbohydrates over time.

Note that our bodies (canine and human) usually handle small quantities of yeast just fine. Live wild yeast occurs naturally on plenty of fruit and other plants. And still dogs (and humans) can eat for example an apple and not have any problems.

Comment: Just to add regarding dogs handling yeast: Brewer's yeast is a popular food/barf addition to support coat changes. As such smaller amounts are really a non issue and usually no reason for concern.

Comment: @Mario yep, B vitamins etc. There’s conflicting information on bakers yeast and as the ASPCA issued  a warning (although more about dogs and cats getting into the bowl with rising dough, which apparently was a frequent occurrence during Covid lockdown), I am not dismissing the possibility entirely. Plus we have no information on dog size - a toy poodle or a GSD with the same roll are two very different stories.